# Switching database dynamically by a parameter in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

*I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.*

I have an instance, which has three databases - A, B, C.

A and B have a table with the same name, and I would like to write a procedure in C that uses the tables in A and B.

```
TEMP_INSTANCE
  - A
    - table TEMP_TABLE
  - B
    - table TEMP_TABLE
  - C
    - stored procedure TEMP_PROCEDURE
```

`TEMP_PROCEDURE` takes a parameter `@P`. If `@P` is `1`, this returns data from `A.TEMP_TABLE`, if `@P` is `2`, then returns those from `B.TEMP_TABLE`. The simplest way I think is using `IF` and makes query in each phrase like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE C.dbo.TEMP_PROCEDURE
    @P tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @P = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM A.dbo.TEMP_TABLE
    END
    ELSE IF @P = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM B.dbo.TEMP_TABLE
    END
END
```

But this way is inefficient because I should write same query in each `IF` phrase. If the number of instance is more than 2, it will be much inefficient whenever there is something to be modified.

My question: is there a cleaner solution? I don't want to repeat the same query in one stored procedure.

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not very well-known syntax but you can call `sp_executesql` in the relevant database, tougher to read perhaps but you don't have to repeat the whole query twice.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE C.dbo.TEMP_PROCEDURE
    @P tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql     nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.TEMP_TABLE;',
            @context nvarchar(max) = CASE @P 
                     WHEN 1 THEN N'A' ELSE N'B' END + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

    EXEC @context @sql;
END
```

Others may suggest `SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @db + '.dbo.TEMP_TABLE';` but I think the approach I've laid out here is both cleaner and less vulnerable to SQL injection.